# How do I use the an array of keys as a filter to sanitize an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that I call `daysArray`. This array represents 2 `days` as illustrated below:

```
console.log(daysArray)
```

Which logs out:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
```

...revealing an array of objects. When further expanded it reveals:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
   0: {Wednesdays: Array(4)}
   1: {Fridays: Array(4)}
```

...it reveals that the objects are two days. Lets further expand:

```
0: 
   Wednesdays: Array(4)
      0: {T_04:00_Start: 1703034000, T_08:00_End: 1703048400}
      1: {T_12:00_Start: 1703062800, T_16:00_End: 1703077200}
      2: {T_16:00_Start: 1703077200, T_20:00_End: 1703091600}
      3: {T_20:00_Start: 1703091600, T_00:00_End: 1703106000}
1: 
   Fridays: Array(4)
      0: {T_04:00_Start: 1703206800, T_08:00_End: 1703221200}
      1: {T_12:00_Start: 1703235600, T_16:00_End: 1703250000}
      2: {T_16:00_Start: 1703250000, T_20:00_End: 1703264400}
      3: {T_20:00_Start: 1703264400, T_00:00_End: 1703278800}
```

...it reveals that each `day` holds 4 time ranges. Each time range has a `start time` **KEY** and a `timestamp` associated to it and an `end time` `KEY` and a timestamp associated to it.

**Note** that the time range **KEYS** for both days (`Fridays` and `Wednesdays`) are all the same.

```
  0: {T_04:00_Start: T_08:00_End:}
  1: {T_12:00_Start: T_16:00_End:}
  2: {T_16:00_Start: T_20:00_End:}
  3: {T_20:00_Start: T_00:00_End:}
```

The following code is supposed to add an additional day to the `daysArray` array called `Tuesdays`, and most importantly, make sure that it only holds the following time ranges to keep it uniformed to the days already existing in the `daysArray` array being **Wednesday** and **Fridays**.

In the code, it is supposed to use the `time ranges` values in the `removedKeys` array to filter out (remove) the unwanted time ranges.

Find below my code:

```
const elementToInsert = "Tuesdays";

// Check if "Tuesdays" is not already in daysArray before proceeding
if (!daysArray.some(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0] === elementToInsert)) {
// Extract time range keys from tempRemovedTimeRanges for Tuesdays
const removedKeys = [...new Set(tempRemovedTimeRanges.flatMap(Object.values).flat().flatMap(Object.keys))];

console.log(removedKeys);


// Iterate through tempRemovedTimeRanges and remove corresponding time ranges from Tuesdays
for (const removedRangeKey of removedKeys) {
  const dayObj = daysArray.find(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(elementToInsert));
  if (dayObj) {
    const originalLength = dayObj[elementToInsert].length;

    dayObj[elementToInsert] = dayObj[elementToInsert].filter(existingRange =>
      !removedKeys.includes(removedRangeKey) ||
      !Object.entries(existingRange).some(([key, value]) =>
        removedRangeKey === key
      )
    );

    const removedCount = originalLength - dayObj[elementToInsert].length;

    console.log(`Removed ${removedCount} time ranges from ${elementToInsert}: `, removedRangeKey);
    console.log(`Updated ${elementToInsert}: `, dayObj[elementToInsert]);
  } else {
    console.log(`${elementToInsert} not found in daysArray.`);
  }
}



// Add "Tuesdays" along with its content back to daysArray
daysArray.push(...tempRemovedTuesdays);
console.log('Restored Tuesdays to daysArray: ', daysArray);

// Clear tempRemovedTuesdays after adding back to daysArray
tempRemovedTuesdays.length = 0;

// Check the everyday checkbox if all the checkboxes are checked!
if (daysArray.length === 7) {
  const checkbox = document.getElementById("_EverydayEveryDay");
  checkbox.checked = true;
  checkbox.disabled = true;
}
} else {
console.log(`${elementToInsert} is already in daysArray.`);
}
```

The following logs out:

```
(4) ['T_00:00_Start', 'T_04:00_End', 'T_08:00_Start', 'T_12:00_End']
Tuesdays not found in daysArray.
Restored Tuesdays to daysArray:  (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Expanding on the `daysArray` reveals that `Tuesdays` was added:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
  0: {Wednesdays: Array(4)}
  1: {Fridays: Array(4)}
  2: {Tuesdays: Array(6)}
```

However that the time ranges aren't uniformed. Lets further expand

```
Fridays: Array(4)
   0: {T_04:00_Start: 1703206800, T_08:00_End: 1703221200}
   1: {T_12:00_Start: 1703235600, T_16:00_End: 1703250000}
   2: {T_16:00_Start: 1703250000, T_20:00_End: 1703264400}
   3: {T_20:00_Start: 1703264400, T_00:00_End: 1703278800}

2: 
  Tuesdays: Array(6)
   0: {T_00:00_Start: 1702933200, T_04:00_End: 1702947600}
   1: {T_04:00_Start: 1702947600, T_08:00_End: 1702962000}
   2: {T_08:00_Start: 1702962000, T_12:00_End: 1702976400}
   3: {T_12:00_Start: 1702976400, T_16:00_End: 1702990800}
   4: {T_16:00_Start: 1702990800, T_20:00_End: 1703005200}
   5: {T_20:00_Start: 1703005200, T_00:00_End: 1703019600}
```

The desired out come for 'Tuesdays' should be:

```
  Tuesdays: Array(4)
   0: {T_04:00_Start: 1702947600, T_08:00_End: 1702962000}
   1: {T_12:00_Start: 1702976400, T_16:00_End: 1702990800}
   2: {T_16:00_Start: 1702990800, T_20:00_End: 1703005200}
   3: {T_20:00_Start: 1703005200, T_00:00_End: 1703019600}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check the list of keys of the object against the list of valid keys

```js
const input = [
   {"T_00:00_Start": 1702933200, "T_04:00_End": 1702947600},
   {"T_04:00_Start": 1702947600, "T_08:00_End": 1702962000},
   {"T_08:00_Start": 1702962000, "T_12:00_End": 1702976400},
   {"T_12:00_Start": 1702976400, "T_16:00_End": 1702990800},
   {"T_16:00_Start": 1702990800, "T_20:00_End": 1703005200},
   {"T_20:00_Start": 1703005200, "T_00:00_End": 1703019600}
];

const validKeys = [
   "T_04:00_Start", "T_12:00_Start", "T_16:00_Start", "T_20:00_Start", "T_08:00_End", "T_16:00_End", "T_20:00_End", "T_00:00_End"
];

const result = input
  .filter((item) => Object.keys(item)
    .every((key) => validKeys.includes(key))
  );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code seems to be in the way you're filtering the time ranges for the "Tuesdays" object. Specifically, there appears to be a problem in the logic you're using to remove the unwanted time ranges based on the `removedKeys` array. The filtering condition inside the `filter` method seems incorrectly formulated.

Let's break down the problem and rewrite the filtering part of your code to correctly remove the unwanted time ranges for "Tuesdays":

1. **Identify Unwanted Time Ranges**: You are correctly identifying the keys to be removed using the `removedKeys` array.
2. **Filtering Time Ranges for Tuesdays**: We need to filter out the time ranges from the "Tuesdays" object that are not required, based on the `removedKeys` array.

Here's a revised version of your code for the filtering part:

```js
// ... [previous code]

// Extract time range keys from tempRemovedTimeRanges for Tuesdays
const removedKeys = [...new Set(tempRemovedTimeRanges.flatMap(Object.values).flat().flatMap(Object.keys))];

console.log(removedKeys);

// Find the Tuesdays object, or create it if it doesn't exist
let dayObj = daysArray.find(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(elementToInsert));
if (!dayObj) {
  dayObj = { [elementToInsert]: [] };
  daysArray.push(dayObj);
}

// Filter out the unwanted time ranges for Tuesdays
const allowedKeys = ['T_04:00_Start', 'T_08:00_End', 'T_12:00_Start', 'T_16:00_End', 'T_16:00_Start', 'T_20:00_End', 'T_20:00_Start', 'T_00:00_End'];
dayObj[elementToInsert] = dayObj[elementToInsert].filter(existingRange =>
  Object.keys(existingRange).every(key => allowedKeys.includes(key))
);

console.log(`Updated ${elementToInsert}: `, dayObj[elementToInsert]);

// ... [rest of your code]
```

In this revised version:

- The `allowedKeys` array is defined to list the keys that should be present in the "Tuesdays" time ranges.
- The filtering logic checks if every key in the current time range (`existingRange`) is included in the `allowedKeys` list.
- If a time range contains any key not in `allowedKeys`, it is filtered out.

This should ensure that the "Tuesdays" object in your `daysArray` only contains the desired time ranges.

Comment: May I kindly request that you make it ready to copy and paste into the console so that I am able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your periods are stable you can filter them by the start date with a regexp in 1 line:

```js
const input = [
   {"T_00:00_Start": 1702933200, "T_04:00_End": 1702947600},
   {"T_04:00_Start": 1702947600, "T_08:00_End": 1702962000},
   {"T_08:00_Start": 1702962000, "T_12:00_End": 1702976400},
   {"T_12:00_Start": 1702976400, "T_16:00_End": 1702990800},
   {"T_16:00_Start": 1702990800, "T_20:00_End": 1703005200},
   {"T_20:00_Start": 1703005200, "T_00:00_End": 1703019600}
];

const result = input.filter(item => Object.keys(item)[0].match(/^T_(04|12|16|20)/));

console.log(result);
```